# Manipulate Template From Block Magento

Tags: magento

I'm trying to change the behavior of the AddtoCart button in the catalog page and show it only in specific cases. What I'm doing is adding a custom module that do the layout updates and replace the Product/List.phtml with my own file. This approach is not very flexible when publishing the custom module, because almost all users will be using a different template file, and they will have to merge mine with theirs.

So my question is can i manipulate the phtml from the block, maybe override *Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List* and alter the template in the *_BeforeToHtml* function, would this be a better approach, is it doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first start by saying that Magento lacks a little flexibility in this area (when rendering to templates). If I am understanding you correctly, you are determining whether the product is salable or not:

- You can add an event to watch for `catalog_product_is_salable_after`. With this way, you are working within the system to set whether the product is available to sell or not. When you change the value of the `salable` `Varien_Object` in the event, it will change it to be an out of stock message. Maybe that is what you want (but the problem is that it is used in an `if/else` statement - it's either available to be added to the cart, or it's out of stock (see code below).
- You could then use a translation file to change *Out of Stock* to the string that you would like there (kind of a hack).
- The problem with trying to override `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` is that the template file is not even included until the `_toHtml` method. You could override that, and call `parent::_toHtml()` at the beginning of the code block. However, to remove the add to cart button would involve some very difficult regular expressions.

Here is the block code. It does get a bit sticky.

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
<?php else: ?>
   <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```